# How to present Usage report to users

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel

Any idea on how to present SP 2013 Usage Reports and view to all users. Right now only the site admin view the report.

Answer (score 1):

- To view the Popularity Trends report for a site collection, the user
  must be a member of the Site Collection Administrators group.
- To view the Popularity Trends report for a site, the user should be a
  member of the Owners group.
- User who is a member of the Visitors group can view the Popularity
  Trends report for a library/list item and view the Most Popular Items
  report for all items in a SharePoint library/list.

Read this article to learn more about [usage reports in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715890.aspx).

To make all users to have access on Usage Reports, an idea is, generate usage report using admin account and store the report in a library. Give all users permissions to the library and the report files, then they can view these reports. Or you can programmatically generate the report in schedule. To get the Usage Reports, you can use [GetRollupAnalyticsItemData method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.searchserviceapplication.getrollupanalyticsitemdata.aspx).

A demo about how to get Usage Reports using PowerShell:

http://technoaspects.blogspot.sg/2013/10/usage-reports-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Audit enabled on your site collection?

You can get specific named reports from Audit if it's enabled. (This is not the same as usage reports). If you're after a particular user's list of actions this is very effective. For a constant general report about all users you'll have to do something with the Audit reports yourself. Get help from this [article](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/track-most-visited-sites-in-sharepoint-2013.html) to display the sites usage reports.

If none of this works, you might have to get a tool that can analyze IIS Logs or get another analytics package installed.

However, the usage reports show up on day 3. Hence you need to wait 2 days.